# Access derived class from virtual method

Tags: c#, inheritance

Though many questions on this topic exist, I am unable to find (yet) a satisfying solution:

**Is it possible (and if yes, how?) to access a derived class from the base virtual method?**

---

Let's imagine I have the following classes:

```
public class parent_class
{
    public virtual string common_method () {
        dynamic child =  /* something to access the derived class */ ;

        if (child == null)
            return typeof(parent_class).FullName;
        else
            return child.GetType().FullName;
    }   
}

public class child_class1 : parent_class {}
public class child_class2 : parent_class {}
public class child_class3 : parent_class {}
```

Is it possible to execute the following code (and getting the correct result)?

```
parent_class p = new parent_class();
child_class1 c1 = new child_class1();
child_class2 c2 = new child_class2();
child_class3 c3 = new child_class3();

System.Console.WriteLine(p.common_method()); // result:  'parent_class'
System.Console.WriteLine(c1.common_method()); // result:  'child_class1'
System.Console.WriteLine(c2.common_method()); // result:  'child_class2'
System.Console.WriteLine(c3.common_method()); // result:  'child_class3'
```

---

**EDIT:** After reading the comments and replies I have to add the following points:

- I have about 300 different "child classes", so overriding is not an option
- I do not want to print the derived class' name - It was just an example
- @Siamak Ferdos: I tried the `this`-keyword, but it somehow did not work as I intended.

Comment: Seems that overriding the virtual method would be the way to go. Any reason you don't do that?

Comment: It's entirely unclear to me what you're trying to do. To get the result you're looking for, you don't need `dynamic` at all, or even for `common_method` to be virtual. Just `return GetType().FullName` will do it. (As an aside, it's useful for follow .NET naming conventions even for test samples.)

Comment: @zneak: There's no need to do that here... the OP can get the result they want without any virtual methods at all...

Comment: What difference does it make that the method is virtual, in your snippet? And what exactly do you want to access (can you give a specific example)?

Comment: _"I do not want to print the derived class' name - It was just an example"_ then _what_ do you want to do? This is pretty important.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: It's some json-serialization, but it somehow only serializes the base class....

Comment: @Unknown6656: I would suggest  you reformulate your question to reflect this, and try to provide clear, concise, and complete program that demonstrates the problem (not serializing the derived class), ideally something we can copy/paste and reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Ok I will do that...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by 'this' keyword simply:

```
public class parent_class
    {
        public virtual string common_method()
        {
            //dynamic child =  /* something to access the derived class */ ;

            if (this.GetType() == typeof(parent_class))
                return typeof(parent_class).FullName;
            else
                return this.GetType().FullName;
        }
    }

    public class child_class1 : parent_class { }
    public class child_class2 : parent_class { }
    public class child_class3 : parent_class { }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to print the classes full name via a common base class method. At runtime, the *actual instantiated type* name is what `GetType().FullName` will produce, not the type of the base class.

This can be tested with a simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    var parent = new Parent();
    var child = new Child();

    Console.WriteLine(parent.GetName());
    Console.WriteLine(child.GetName());
}

public class Parent
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return this.GetType().FullName; 
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
}
```

Yields:

```
UserQuery+Parent
UserQuery+Child
```

Where `UserQuery` is the defined namespace.

There is no need for the method to be virtual or overriden in the derived class for this to work.